# How to aggregate values while deriving weighted averages in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a requirement to derive a consumption percentage whose logic is based on weighted averages. Below is the code I am running.
    I am trying to find out the value of Consensus_Plan_Consumption_pc field at a different level of aggregation. This can be by week, by month, by year, etc. However, If I run the below code, I see 12 values for 1 year basically that is due to the inp.t_ep_fiscal_month_id field which gives me fiscal months. I want to know how should I write the code so that it can itself aggregate when the user demands it as a month, a year or quarter level.

```
SELECT item1.item,
    fiscal_year,inp.t_ep_fiscal_month_id , curr_fscl_month.t_ep_fiscal_month_id,
case when inp.t_ep_fiscal_month_id < curr_fscl_month.t_ep_fiscal_month_id 
        then 
        (sum(nvl(sales.actual_quantity, 0) *1 ) / sum( sales.xxdm_dp_plan_pm *1))
        else 
        ( 
        case when 
        (sum(case when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(sales.sales_date), 'yyyyMMdd') <curr_fscl_month.pval then nvl(sales.actual_quantity, 0)
        else
        DECODE(NVL(sales.xxdm_cons_flag,1)
        ,1,NVL(sales.wcp_override, 0) + NVL(sales.xxdm_ref_dp_override, 0) + NVL( sales.xxdm_asia_dp_override , 0 )
        ,NVL(sales.xxdm_combined_fcst,0))
        end )) > 0 
        then (sum(nvl(sales.actual_quantity,0) + nvl(xxdm_open_orders,0))) / ((sum(case when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(sales.sales_date), 'yyyyMMdd') <curr_fscl_month.pval then nvl(sales.actual_quantity, 0)
        else
        DECODE(NVL(sales.xxdm_cons_flag,1)
        ,1,NVL(sales.wcp_override, 0) + NVL(sales.xxdm_ref_dp_override, 0) + NVL( sales.xxdm_asia_dp_override , 0 )
        ,NVL(sales.xxdm_combined_fcst,0))
        end )))
        end
        ) Consensus_Plan_Consumption_pc
FROM prod_corp_frank.sales_data sales
LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_comres_sc_core.xxdm_dm_comb_v app ON (sales.item_id = app.item_id AND sales.location_id = app.location_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
  SELECT inp.datet,
          fs_month.T_EP_FISCAL_MONTH_CODE fiscal_month,
          fs_week.T_EP_FISCAL_WEEK_CODE fiscal_week,
          fs_quarter.T_EP_FISCAL_quarter_CODE fiscal_quarter,
          inp.t_ep_fiscal_year_id fiscal_year,
          inp.t_ep_fiscal_month_id
   FROM prod_corp_frank.inputs inp
   LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_corp_frank.t_ep_fiscal_month fs_month ON (inp.t_ep_fiscal_month_id = fs_month.t_ep_fiscal_month_id)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_corp_frank.t_ep_fiscal_week fs_week ON (inp.t_ep_fiscal_week_id = fs_week.t_ep_fiscal_week_id)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_corp_frank.t_ep_fiscal_quarter fs_quarter ON (inp.t_ep_fiscal_quarter_id = fs_quarter.t_ep_fiscal_quarter_id)
   ) inp 
   ON (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(sales.sales_date), 'yyyyMMdd') = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(inp.datet), 'yyyyMMdd'))
LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_comres_sc_core.xxdm_dm_item_v item1 ON (sales.item_id = item1.item_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_corp_frank.t_ep_item tand1 on (item1.xxdm_tandem_item1=tand1.t_ep_item_ep_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_corp_frank.t_ep_item tand2 on (item1.xxdm_tandem_item2=tand2.t_ep_item_ep_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_corp_frank.t_ep_item tand3 on (item1.xxdm_tandem_item3=tand3.t_ep_item_ep_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_comres_sc_core.xxdm_dm_loc_v loc ON sales.location_id = loc.location_id,
(
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(sys.pval,'MM-dd-yyyy'), 'yyyyMMdd') pval,
inp1.t_ep_fiscal_month_id
from prod_corp_frank.SYS_PARAMS sys,
prod_corp_frank.inputs inp1
where pname='min_fore_sales_date'
and from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(sys.pval,'MM-dd-yyyy'), 'yyyyMMdd')
= from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(inp1.datet), 'yyyyMMdd')
) curr_fscl_month --calculate current fiscal_month
WHERE item1.item='ZP98'
and fiscal_year between 2016 and 2019
    GROUP BY item1.item,
    fiscal_year,
    inp.t_ep_fiscal_month_id,
    curr_fscl_month.t_ep_fiscal_month_id
```

Comment: Can you minimize this problem?

Comment: This is the code in short.... if(
getrow()<forecastfirstrow,
(sales/xxdm_dp_plan_pm),
(
 if(
  fcst_consensus>0,
  (if(isnull(sales),0,sales)+if(isnull(xxdm_open_orders),0,xxdm_open_orders)
  )/fcst_consensus,0)
  )
)

Comment: Presumably, your joins produce a dataset that you then want to aggregate. It would help us a lot if you could edit your question to include a sample dataset you're trying to aggregate, and the output you're expecting. That way, we stand a much better chance of trying to work out what you're trying to do, and the best way of doing it.

Comment: @Boneist so this data as you can see it is by month. Now I will be creating a view out of it (create view view_name as....). Now if I query that view and want to aggregate the results per year, how will I do it? Because the granularity of data is by month. But when I want it by year on top of that view, how will I write statement so that "Consensus_Plan_Consumption_pc" is calculated per year?